# SPFx web part to modify left navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, navigation

Is it possible to build a SPFx web part which can replace the left navigation? I would like to create my own navigation that will use a treeview control.

When I edit my sharepoint site I can insert a web part only in the main window. When I edit a navigation I have no option to customize it with a web part.

From what I have seen there are number of SPFx examples on how to replace footer and header but I couldn't find an example that customizes the left navigation.

Comment: The following post suggests to use sharepoint extensions
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265314/spfx-webpart-component-with-position-fixed

Comment: Here is an example of customizing the left navigation using SPFx, please refer to it: https://github.com/cleferman/spfx-custom-left-navigation

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way supported by Microsoft for customizing left navigation using SPFx (web part or application customizer) like top/bottom placeholders in SPFx application customizer.

You have below two ways:

1. Move quick launch navigation from left side to top side using "Horizontal" orientation from navigation settings. Then develop left navigation on your own using SPFx and/or DOM manipulation.

   Follow: [New Navigation features for SharePoint team sites](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/17/new-navigation-features-for-sharepoint-team-sites/)
2. Hide left navigation items using DOM manipulation and inject your own navigation links using custom HTML/JS.

**Examples**:

1. [SPFx Side Navigation Project for Modern Sites](https://thomasdaly.net/2020/06/09/spfx-side-navigation-project-for-modern-sites/)
2. [Custom Quick Launch using Fluent UI Nav in SPFx](https://ravichandran.blog/2020/06/02/custom-quick-launch-using-fluent-ui-nav-in-spfx/)